# GRASS shell commands not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, network, shell

Running GRASS 6.4.3 within QGIS 2.4.0 on Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite. I'm trying to run v.net.iso within the GRASS shell, but the following error is returned every time:

```
bash: v.net.iso: command not found
```

I did this successfully two weeks ago before I upgraded to Yosemite, but have not been able to get it work since. I've tried a number of other commands in the shell module, and I get the same error each time.

Comment: Please add the output of "g.version -g" (best is that you edit your questions)

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with the Shell where it does not load the Grass /bin into $PATH
My solution is to do it manually inside the Shell.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

$ PATH="/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/bin:$PATH"
$ export PATH
$ echo $PATH
/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also on OSX Yosemite using QGIS and GRASS, the GRASS shell in QGIS doesn't start, but it's hard to use anyways (It's hard to copy-paste, the font is hard to read and there is no cursor or command history).

I start GRASS in the OSX Terminal, doing all analysis there, while I use GRASS in QGIS to export shapefiles into the GRASS database, and to load them back into QGIS, without problems of a locked GRASS server.

In Terminal start GRASS using

`$ Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/grass.sh`